# Is data sent to an Apple wireless bluetooth keyboard, for example when the Caps Lock key is turned on?

Tags: macbook, bluetooth, wireless-keyboard, hid

I have a 2009 MacBook with OS X Lion.

On a bluetooth connected keyboard, can I send data to the keyboard? AT keyboards for example, all the LEDs are turned on and off by the PC.

Does the same thing still happen or is the Caps Lock LED turned on locally now?

Answer (score 4):

It certainly looks like the PC still manages the LED:

1. The functions of my <kbd>caps-lock</kbd> and left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys are swapped in System Preferences, yet the LED on the <kbd>caps-lock</kbd> key still tracks the caps-lock function correctly.
2. With Bluetooth on the PC turned off and the keyboard still on, the caps lock LED doesn't respond to either key.